How to use sqlalchemy limit with join
Fastapi app. I have models
class State(str, enum.Enum):
    WATCHING = "WATCHING"
    WATCHED = "WATCHED"
    DROPPED = "DROPPED"

class Anime(Base):
    __tablename__ = "anime"
    uuid = Column(UUID, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = Column(String(128), nullable=False, unique=True)
    state = Column(Enum(State), default=State.WATCHING)
    rate = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    review = Column(String(4096), nullable=True)
    start_end = relationship(
        "AnimeStartEnd",
        back_populates="anime",
        order_by="AnimeStartEnd.start_date",
        lazy="joined"
    )

class AnimeStartEnd(Base):
    __tablename__ = "anime_start_end"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    start_date = Column(Date)
    end_date = Column(Date, nullable=True)
    anime_id = Column(UUID, ForeignKey("anime.uuid"))
    anime = relationship("Anime", back_populates="start_end")

And I have service.py with get_anime_list function
async def get_anime_list(session: AsyncSession, limit: int, page: int):
    subq = (
        select(models.AnimeStartEnd)
        .order_by(models.AnimeStartEnd.start_date)
        .subquery()
    )
    stmt = (
        select(models.Anime)
        .join(subq)
        .options(joinedload(models.Anime.start_end))
        .limit(limit)
        .offset((page - 1) * limit)
    )

    result = await session.execute(stmt)
    anime_list = result.scalars().unique().all()

    return anime_list

I want to get list of all anime with their start_end represented as list of start_end sorted by anime_start_end.start_date with applied limit and offset. Schema look like this:
[
  {
    "name": "string",
    "state": "WATCHED",
    "rate": 1,
    "review": "string",
    "start_end": [
      {
        "start_date": "2024-08-19",
        "end_date": "2024-08-29"
      },
      {
        "start_date": "2024-09-19",
        "end_date": "2024-09-19"
      }
    ],
    "uuid": "string"
  }
]

But limit is applied to subquery and i getting wrong number of anime. E.g. with limit 5 and offset 0: db anime_start_end dump sorted by start_date and it getting this 4 anime_ids and all their start_end data.
id  start_date  end_date    anime_id                               | anime.name
9   2006-02-22  2016-09-12  6fe17741-527d-4537-b11f-7a0aa54b40fc   | Naruto
20  2006-04-13  2007-08-22  8a2dfd03-e856-45de-80fc-2db8ad519555   | Shaman King
17  2016-09-13  2016-09-20  ba377637-8c3c-4a0d-9ea7-2ec50ad260e8   | ...
18  2017-05-23  2017-05-25  ba377637-8c3c-4a0d-9ea7-2ec50ad260e8   | ...
13  2020-01-01  2020-02-02  2ca9fa6c-197a-47dc-8b5b-61bf30fcfa0c   | ...

[
  {
    "name": "Naruto",
    "state": "WATCHED",
    "rate": 10,
    "review": "its been a long way",
    "start_end": [
      {
        "start_date": "2006-02-22",
        "end_date": "2016-09-12"
      }
    ],
    "uuid": "6fe17741-527d-4537-b11f-7a0aa54b40fc"
  },
  {
    "name": "Shamag King",
    "state": "WATCHED",
    "rate": 9,
    "review": "best opening",
    "start_end": [
      {
        "start_date": "2006-04-13",
        "end_date": "2007-08-22"
      }
    ],
    "uuid": "8a2dfd03-e856-45de-80fc-2db8ad519555"
  },
  {
    "name": "Haikyuu!",
    "state": "WATCHED",
    "rate": 10,
    "review": "best sport anime",
    "start_end": [
      {
        "start_date": "2016-09-13",
        "end_date": "2016-09-20"
      },
      {
        "start_date": "2017-05-23",
        "end_date": "2017-05-25"
      },
      {
        "start_date": "2024-09-01",
        "end_date": "2024-09-04"
      }
    ],
    "uuid": "ba377637-8c3c-4a0d-9ea7-2ec50ad260e8"
  },
  {
    "name": "Testing transaction 2",
    "state": "WATCHED",
    "rate": 3,
    "review": "not yet",
    "start_end": [
      {
        "start_date": "2020-01-01",
        "end_date": "2020-02-02"
      },
      {
        "start_date": "2024-06-25",
        "end_date": "2024-09-11"
      }
    ],
    "uuid": "2ca9fa6c-197a-47dc-8b5b-61bf30fcfa0c"
  }
]

How can i get anime_list of length==limit (with start_date sorting)?
SOLVED:
subq = (
    select(models.AnimeStartEnd.anime_id)
    .group_by(models.AnimeStartEnd.anime_id)
    .order_by(func.min(models.AnimeStartEnd.start_date))
    .limit(limit)
    .offset((page - 1) * limit)
    .subquery()
)
stmt = (
    select(models.Anime)
    .join(subq)
    .options(joinedload(models.Anime.start_end))
)

